# EXCEL sum and sumifs excluding multiple words

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The formula I am entering below works only with one condition I use the <> sign in example 1. The problem I have is when I enter two <> as shown in example 2 it doubles my total value and doesn’t work. How would I enter two <> conditions to get a dollar value for revenue?
For example my revenue result will be 75,000 in example one, but in example 2 I get 150,000. Don’t understand what is happening. Probably a simple mistake I am making.

1)  =SUM(SUMIFS(Revdata!O:O,Revdata!N:N,Sheet2!B3,Revdata!J:J,{"<>dog"}))

2)  =SUM(SUMIFS(Revdata!O:O,Revdata!N:N,Sheet2!B3,Revdata!J:J,{"<>dog","<>cat"}))

Comment: When doing an array like that it is an OR. So since you are looking at one cell at a time it will always return true, if it is dog it will not = cat and return true and vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

You can repeat, inside `SUMIFS`, the same range with another condition. This way you're asking that *both* conditions are satisfied, not *any of them*.

BTW you wont need `SUM`, just `SUMIFS`:

```
=SUMIFS(RevData!O:O,RevData!N:N,Sheet2!B3,RevData!J:J,"<>dog",RevData!J:J,"<>cat")
```

Comment: Better, I got caught being anchored by the OP's method

Comment: @ScottCraner yeah, I imagined that ;)

Comment: I solved it doing it the other way around. Where I only want those exact words    =SUMIFS(RevData!O:O,RevData!N:N,Sheet2!B3,RevData!J:J,{"dog","cat"})