# How to exclude multiple strings from SUMIFS

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, sumifs, textjoin

I have this formula here:

```
=SUMIFS(SalesData!$N:$N, SalesData!$B:$B, "FirstName LastName", SalesData!$D:$D, "<>"&A1:M1)
```

But the last part `"<>"&A1:M1` doesn't work correctly. If I set it to a specific cell, e.g. `"<>"&F1`, that works fine. Is there a way to select the entire range of A1:M1?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Can you share screenshots or copy of your spreadsheet? Please remove any sensitive data if there are any. We can help you better if we can see and understand your spreadsheet so we can replicate and experiment on our end and also so we can see what error is being thrown. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Also see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44166219/excel-sum-and-sumifs-excluding-multiple-words

Comment: Unfortunately it's purchase data from our customers and commission data for our employees, so I can't share details. Basically in `A1:M1`, each cell has an employee's name. Sometimes an employee will sell something to another employee and their name will show up under "Customer" in `SalesData!D:D` Those sales are not commissionable and need to not be counted in the total `SUMIFS` formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=SUM(FILTER(SalesData!N:N, SalesData!B:B="FirstName LastName", 
 NOT(REGEXMATCH(SalesData!D:D&"", TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A1:M1)))))
```